# Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout max width of bottom sheet (how to set)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm unable to set the maximum width of the bottom sheet in the ModalBottomSheetLayout. I've tried the following but that changes the entire page's maximum width, not just the bottom sheet:

```
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.requiredWidthIn(max = 640.dp),
        ... // rest of code not shown
```

The [Material specs](https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-sheets/specs) say to set a maximum width of 640dp for bottom sheets. How do we comply with this requirement?

I [filed a bug with Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/269654981) but wasn't sure if anyone has insight on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()`.

Moreover you can find out max width of screen by using [BoxWithConstraint](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive#flexible-nested-reusable)

Example:

```
BoxWithConstraints {
    val widthModifier = if (maxWidth < 400.dp) {
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    } else {
        Modifier.width(640.dp)
    }
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        modifier = *yourModifier*.then(widthModifier),
        ...
}
```